# Django - multiple models(table) in one view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

OS - Windows10
Python - 3.7.4
Django - 2.1

I want to show this models. like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UERg.jpg)

but i don't know. How can i do that. I tried to solve this problem for 3months :(
already I have MySQL Database. So, I have to stay these Data Structure(Models)

Admin Inheritance?
Override Queryset in Django Admin?

I don't know how to do that. I didn't under stand Queryset,str,ORM...

Because I just have started Django for 3months.

I have to fix this problem. Multiple models(table==class) in one view(templates)

But I can't.. Please Tell me the hint, Solution, anything

## Models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Exam(models.Model):
    idexam = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    trueanswernum = models.IntegerField(db_column='trueAnswerNum', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    falseanswernum = models.IntegerField(db_column='falseAnswerNum', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    exammain = models.TextField(db_column='examMain', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    questionsubmain = models.TextField(db_column='questionSubMain', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    answerno1 = models.TextField(db_column='answerNo1', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    answerno2 = models.TextField(db_column='answerNo2', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    answerno3 = models.TextField(db_column='answerNo3', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    answerno4 = models.TextField(db_column='answerNo4', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    rightanswer = models.IntegerField(db_column='rightAnswer', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    originalremark = models.TextField(db_column='originalRemark', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    writer = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    writingdate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='writingDate', blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sources = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'boards_exam'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.exammain

class Examhistory(Exam):
    idexamhistory = models.AutoField(db_column='idExamhistory', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    idexam = models.IntegerField()
    examyear = models.IntegerField(db_column='examYear')  # Field name made lowercase.
    examtypecode = models.IntegerField(db_column='examTypeCode')  # Field name made lowercase.
    yearexamnum = models.IntegerField(db_column='yearExamNum', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    examsubj = models.IntegerField(db_column='examSubj', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    examnum = models.IntegerField(db_column='examNum', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'boards_examhistory'
        unique_together = (('idexamhistory', 'idexam'),)


class Examtype(models.Model):
    examtypecode = models.IntegerField(db_column='examTypeCode', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    examtypename = models.CharField(db_column='examTypeName', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'boards_examtype'


class Lawinfo(models.Model):
    lawnamecode = models.IntegerField(db_column='lawNameCode', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lawname = models.CharField(db_column='lawName', max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lawadmin = models.CharField(db_column='lawAdmin', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'boards_lawinfo'


class Lawtext(models.Model):
    idlawtext = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    lawnamecode = models.IntegerField(db_column='lawNameCode', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lawcategory = models.IntegerField(db_column='lawCategory', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lawcontent_jo = models.CharField(db_column='lawContent_jo', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lawcontent_hang = models.CharField(db_column='lawContent_hang', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lawcontent_ho = models.CharField(db_column='lawContent_ho', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lawcontent_mok = models.CharField(db_column='lawContent_mok', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lawtext = models.TextField(db_column='lawText', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'boards_lawtext'


class Relatedlaw(models.Model):
    idrelatedlaw = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    idexam = models.IntegerField()
    lawnamecode = models.IntegerField(db_column='lawNameCode', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lawcategory = models.CharField(db_column='lawCategory', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lawcontent_jo = models.CharField(db_column='lawContent_jo', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lawcontent_hang = models.CharField(db_column='lawContent_hang', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lawcontent_ho = models.CharField(db_column='lawContent_ho', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lawcontent_mok = models.CharField(db_column='lawContent_mok', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'boards_relatedlaw'
        unique_together = (('idrelatedlaw', 'idexam'),)

# Create your models here.
```

## Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Exam

def exam_list(request):
    exams = Exam.objects.filter(writingdate__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('writingdate')
    return render(request, 'boards/exam_list.html', {'exams': exams})

def exam_detail(request, pk):
    exam = get_object_or_404(Exam, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'boards/exam_detail.html', {'exam': exam})
# Create your views here.
```

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Exam

admin.site.register(Exam)
# Register your models here.
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? it is not very clear. Where do you want to implement this structure? in admin or in custom template

Comment: @NalinDobhal Just I have to implement 1 template(detail.html) using 6 class(models.py). But I don't know. How can I do that

Comment: you need data of 6 models in 1 template/view? or you want to implement something else?

Comment: @NalinDobhal yes I just need data of 6 models in 1 template/view. I can 1 models 1queryset in template/view. But I can't solve multiple models in 1 view/template

Comment: add your views code

Comment: @NalinDobhal Done. I add views and admin code

Answer (score 11):

I might not understand your application, but if you want to load data from multiple models in a view, you can override the `get_context_data` method of the generic class based views. Here is an example using [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView).

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from .models import Exam, Lawtext


class PageView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "pagename.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['exams'] = Exam.objects.all()
        context['lawtexts'] = Lawtext.objects.all()
        return context
```

Then in your `appname/templates/appname/pagename.html` you have access to the data you queried in the view. In this case we get all the data from the models Exam and Lawtext. You could easily extend this.

```
{% for exam in exams %}
    <h4>{{exam.exammain}} </h4>
    <p>{{exam.rightanswer}}</p>
{% endfor %} 

{% for lawtext in lawtexts %}
    <p>{{lawtext.lawnamecode}}</p>
    <p>{{lawtext.lawcategory}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

---

OK, so I see you added added your views after I started writing my answer... 
If you use function based views and return using [render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render), you can do this in a similar way. Your views.py can look something like this:

```
from .models import Exam, Lawtext

def exam_list(request):
    exams = Exam.objects.filter(writingdate__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('writingdate')
    lawtexts = Lawtext.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'boards/exam_list.html', {'exams': exams, 'lawtexts': lawtexts})
```