# Combining two models into one in django

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to combine two models into one in django so that I can show all details of both table in django admin panel in one table.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    gst_no = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
```

```
class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='address')
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    apartment_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = CountryField(multiple=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ADDRESS_CHOICES)
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    used_in_orders = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    display = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def gst_no(self):
        return self.user.gst_no if self.user.gst_no else None
```

I know there is Inline method but I don't. want that I want to show all details of both models into one separate table

Comment: You need to be more specific about where/how you want this data to be displayed - Are you talking about the list page of one/both models? Are you talking about the edit page for one/both models? Can a User can have multiple Addresses?

Comment: Hey In Django Admin panel I want to view Address and User fields in one separate table so that admin don't need to go to Address tab or User tab to see the details of two tables.

Comment: Can a User can have multiple Addresses?

Comment: @MdShahbazAhmad Yes user can have multiple Address. It is like delivery addresses like in ecommerce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your expectation, you want to implement this on the Django admin panel. One way to achieve this is by using **join between the User and Address models using select_related().**

I register the Address model and override the **get_queryset()** method to write the expected **queryset** and write **callable** to display the User model fields.

```
@admin.register(Address)
class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone', 'username', 'company_name',
        'street_address', 'apartment_address', 'country', 'state', 'city', 'zip', 'address_type', 'default', 'used_in_orders', 'display'
    ]

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        queryset = queryset.select_related("user").all()
        return queryset

    def first_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.first_name

    def last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.last_name

    def email(self, obj):
        return obj.user.email

    def phone(self, obj):
        return obj.user.phone

    def username(self, obj):
        return obj.user.username

    def company_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.company_name
```

If you want to change the page name, you change the verbose_name of the Address model (for example, 'User Detail')

```
class Address(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User Detail'
        verbose_name_plural = 'User Details'
```

You can also use Proxy model of Address for this if you don't want to use Address model.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create a custom view where you blend the data from the two models into a single table and add it to the Django Admin Site.

[The Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites) explains how you can make and integrate custom views into the Django Admin Site.

The TL;DR is to create a [Django View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) that displays the data the way you want and then insert the view by overriding the `get_urls` method for the `AdminSite` class.

```py
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super().get_urls()
    my_urls = [path("my_view/", self.admin_site.admin_view(self.my_view))]
    return my_urls + urls
```

This [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59369795/12197596) shows an example of how you can blend data from multiple tables in a single view if that is something you are unfamiliar with.

Comment: Hey thank you for the new information. But I don't have anything to do with views here, I only need to combine both models fields to show in separate tab in Django admin panel only.